# How to get real-time data on new data insert into MySQL db

Tags: mysql, laravel, axios, pusher

I am using Laravel and pusher. Pusher is working good. But I want to know how can I get data when I will insert new data into database?

Process is if someone push/insert data on the table, then those data will automatically show without reloading the page.

Can anyone explain it? or give me any documentation or video link about it?

Answer (score 2):

What you need are [Broadcast Events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events).

Let's assume that you are inserting a `Post` and you want all users to get notified about a new post, therefore refresh the posts table index.
All your users should be subscribed to a presence channel, but you could use private or public channel. IMO, presence channel works better for this scenario since you are dispatching just 1 event for all users instead of 1 event per user in case of private channel

In your `store` function in `PostController.php` you dispatch the event once `Post` has been created:

```
use App\Events\PostCreated;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Insert new post
    $post = Post::create($request->all());

    // Dispatch broadcast
    PostCreated::dispatch($post);

    return $result;
}
```

Then in your `PostCreated.php` Event, you send the post itself as the event payload:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class PostCreated implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $afterCommit = true;

    public Post $post;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Post $post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    /**
     * The event's broadcast name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'post.created';
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('posts');
    }
}
```

Now you need that all users subscribe to the right channel. Assuming, again, that you are using laravel echo, this is how I do it within a Vue Js app by joining a presence channel `posts` and listening for `post.created` event.

```
this.echoInstance.join('posts')
    .listen('.post.created', (post) => {
        // Do something like refresh table 
        // or insert `post` object directly in posts array
    })
```

Since you didn't provide any code, this is a generic sample. Next time, please share what you've done so far.